# Possible Conference Speaking Sponsorships -- 2011

Tags: discussion, conferences

We're evaluating the feasibility of **sponsoring a member of the gamedev community to speak at a conference in 2011**.

Speaking is a relatively big "ask", so this needs to be planned many months in advance. Let's get started!

We'd like the community to establish **where** ...

> What relevant game developers' conferences are coming up in 2011 that have open speaker slots or calls for papers?

... and then **who**.

> Which members of the community are strongly interested in being sponsored by Stack Exchange, Inc to speak at one of the above conferences in 2011?

To be clear, the speaker is free talk about anything he or she wants so long as it would be roughly on topic for this site -- with a quick acknowledgement of support from Stack Exchange and a mention of the community here.

Comment: What does it mean to speak? Do i have to speak about gdse? Or it is about speaking about something proffesional and just propagating gdse by showing it exists and there are proffesionals here?

Comment: @nota "speaking about something proffesional and just propagating gdse by showing it exists and there are proffesionals here" -- this, exactly. We just want to enable avid members of the community to speak, as game developers, on topics that interest them.

Answer (score 6):

If i can speak about my work (or better work of team i'm part of) i would love to speak on conference. I also really like this site and community and would like to propagate it. I work on renderer for movies integrated into Maya based on gpu rasterization - c++/directx11 (nobody did that before). So my contribution can be something like "How did we made whole feature movie on something like game engine"... Or just start discussion like "Do we still need raytracing?" or maybe somebody might be interested in "Volumetric effects into game engine", which is my current work.

I just propose. Not sure if this is correct answer here. I'm presenting it in computer graphics conference in three weeks, so i will see how succesful i will be.

[renderer can be found here](http://furryball.aaa-studio.eu/), current version is capable to do much more than what you can see on a website. But images have to be keep secret at the moment because all of them are part of the movie. Teaser will be available soon (no secrets then) so you can consider the curent quality of renderer. Also something can be found on [my youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/pasovec) (with programmer art warning).

**tl;dr;** : I propose myself to speak about renderer which uses game like technology to provide same outputs (1:1) as build in high quality renderers in Autodesk Maya, but 50-1000 times faster.

**Edit**: Here is **[teaser to the movie](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Adlwgr0Hd8&feature=mfu_in_order&list=UL)** (with EN subtitles). I also was presenting this renderer on a computer graphics conference, i think i was kinda successful, people liked it :). So i feel to be qualified enough now.

Answer (score 3):

GDC San Fran, one of the largest conferences, has just finished. GDC Europe is in August but is closed for submissions.

GDC Online (http://www.gdconline.com/) is still open for subs until the 5th May, and it runs 10-13th October in Austin, Texas.

I may be being thick but I can't find anything on GDC China's website (http://www.gdcchina.com/) about submission deadlines.

The Paris Game/AI Conference (http://gameaiconf.com/) is also closed for submissions this year.

Having said that, for 2011 I am looking to apply to speak at a range of these conferences. As long as it sat well with my employers I would be willing to be sponsored by stackexchange.

Answer (score 3):

> *Corollary to https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2052/possible-conference-speaking-sponsorships-2011/2059#2059*

PAX is probably viewed as much more of a consumer-based conference, but I'd imagine their [PAX Dev conference](http://dev.paxsite.com/index.php) in Seattle, August 24-25, would have many more indie-type devs at it who are a lot more open about matters of development than larger houses.  They are currently looking for [speakers and panelists](http://devpanels.paxsite.com/) through June 1.

I don't create games, so just tossing this out there.